# How to draw a hub-centered network diagram in matlab?

Tags: networking, graph, drawing, matlab

I am wondering if matlab has some functions of toolbox to draw networks in a hub-centered way like this:

[image: hub-centered network diagram]

I have a connectivity matrix of nodes. The directions of edges and color are not so important. Only the hub-centered style is desired. I have checked the biography toolbox but it seems to be drawing network in a random way. I found some tools online which are either implemented in other languages or as commercial software. Or matlab simply can not do it? Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for graph visualization is probably GraphViz: http://www.graphviz.org/

It can do basically whatever you want it to (within reason).  We use it inside our toolboxes to do our graphical layouts.  And people use it to make pretty plots when they don't want to reinvent the wheel to do graph layouts (which are *not* trivial, especially for large graphs).

There's a google project to get GraphViz into MATLAB here: http://code.google.com/p/graphviz4matlab/

I haven't used it, but it looks sweet.  It is released under GPL, so if that's a concern, a toolbox I've been working on: http://www.newfolderconsulting.com/prt/ has very limited support  for graph visualization tools.  e.g.

```
prtPath('alpha');
connMat = [0 1 1 1 1 0; 1 0 1 0 1 0; 1 1 0 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 0];
nodeNames = {'pete','kenny','sam','wiki','samantha','elena'};

graph = prtDataTypeGraph(connMat,nodeNames);
graph.plot; 
title('People (and dogs) Who Worked or Lived Together');
```

Internally, it also makes use of the GraphViz tools, but not through the google code project.

I can't stress enough how "alpha" the graph-visualization code in the PRT is.  If GPL is not an issue, the google code project looks like a pretty good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the GraphViz Matlab via the google code project. It provided a  easy starting point. Thanks again.